# MVC page ajax request base URL

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

While making an ajax request to a Controller action I'm trying to get the url of the page from which the ajax request is being triggered.

Using Request.RawUrl in the action is returning the ajax request url as the current request in ajax request. Is there any way to know the actual url of the page from which the ajax request is being triggered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller method use

[`Request.UrlReferrer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

This should give you the url of the ajax request's origin.

Comment: I'm not looking for the ajax request url. I'm looking for the page on which the request was triggered. If I;m on localhost/home/index and an ajax request is triggered to localhost/home/ajaxhandler then inside the ajaxhandler action method I need to get the url of the page on which the request was triggered. In this case that being localhost/home/index.

Comment: I just ran sample code with an AJAX request and the `Request.UrlReferrer.OriginalString` (`http://blah:61713/` which is where I made the AJAX request) is different to the `Request.Url.OriginalString` (`http://blah:61713/Home/GetTasks`). I assume this isn't what you're looking for?